# Parse data from CSV file in C

Tags: c, csv

I am trying to parse a CSV file that I am importing into the programme. I am trying to use the strtok function, and a while function to check each read each token and assign it to a variable.

When I run this code, there are no errors:

```
void Import_and_Print()
{
    printf("\nPlace for importing files and printing results.\n\n");
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;
    int grade;

    char csvData[] = "Student Name,Course_1,Course_2,Course_3,Course_4";
    int i = 0;
    const char s[2] = ",";
    char *dataArr[7] = {0};
    char *token;

    token = strtok(csvData,s);

    while (token != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", token);
        dataArr[i++] = token;
        printf("Array entry %d:\t%s\n", i, dataArr[i]);
        token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }
}
```

However, when I run this code, I get a number of errors:

```
void Import_and_Print()
{
    printf("\nPlace for importing files and printing results.\n\n");
    FILE * fp;
    char * line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;

    ssize_t read;
    int grade;

    fp = fopen("CTASample.csv", "r");
    if (fp == NULL)
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
     
    read = getline(&line, &len, fp);
    char csvDate[] = read;
    int i = 0;
    const char s[2] = ",";
    char *dataArr[7] = {0};
    char *token;

    token = strtok(csvData,s);

    while (token != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", token);
        dataArr[i++] = token;
        printf("Array entry %d:\t%s\n", i, dataArr[i]);
        token = strtok(NULL, s);
    }
}
```

The error message I get is:

> Grades.c: In function ‘Import_and_Print’:

> Grades.c:37:22: error: invalid initializer    37 |     char csvDate[] = read;

Any suggestions on how to resolve?

Comment: You don't need the `csvdata` variable in this case.  Just use `line`.

Comment: You're trying to assign an integer to a character array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few bugs in your code probably from bad copy-paste. Here you are:

1. `csvDate` is a character buffer. Don't assign `read` bytes into buffer. Just assign the `line` to `csvData` or simply use `line`.

```c
char *csvDate = line;
```

2. You should remember for `free` the dynamically allocated `line` buffer at the end of the function.
3. Don't increment `i` before using the same index.

```c
    dataArr[i] = token;
    printf("Array entry %d:\t%s\n", i, dataArr[i]);
    i += 1;
```

4. Assuming the csv has at most 7 columns is something you can not rely on.  try to allocate a dynamically (re-)allocated array to account for lines with more columns.

Comment: Thank you for this. Thanks for this. As you can gather, I'm new to C and it can be far more elaborate than Python which I'm more use to

Answer (score 1):

There are three things wrong with the line

`char csvDate[] = read;`

1. It contains a typo. You probably intended to write `csvData` instead of `csvDate`, since other parts of your program also use the identifier `csvData`.
2. If you want to copy a string, you cannot use `=` for that (unless you use it inside a declaration for initializing a character array using a string literal). You must use `strcpy` instead.
3. In this case, you cannot simply use `[]` to make the compiler ensure that enough memory is allocated to store the string. This only works when initializing a character array using a string literal inside a declaration.

However, as already stated in the comments section, there is no need to copy the string. You don't need two separate strings `csvData` and `line`. You can pass `line` directly to `strtok` and remove `csvData` from your program. Or you can rename `line` to `csvData` everywhere in your program, so that you only have one string.

Also, as pointed out in the other answer, you are incrementing `i` in the wrong place in your program.

Additionally, it is worth mentioning that your program contains a memory leak and a resource leak. You are not freeing the memory returned by `getline` and you are not closing the file that you opened.

Comment: Thanks for this. As you can gather, I'm new to C and it can be far more elaborate than Python which I'm more use to.

Comment: @Clauric: If you find handling the memory management of strings too complicated in C and want the compiler to take care of the memory management for you, and if you want to be able to use `=` to copy strings, then you may want to take a look at C++. There, you have the [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class, which has all these features and it behaves in a similar way as strings in scripting languages. On the other hand, learning how strings are handled on a low-level of abstraction can be important, too.

Comment: Unfortuneately, at the moment, I am learning C simply because it is a requirement of an academic course I am doing. The lecturer is not particularily helpful, and his lecutre notes don't cover much in the way of coding, so I am trying to learn it on my own. I might look at C++ at a later date.